# NLog Improving Rendering Performance

Tags: c#, nlog

Is it possible to somehow improve NLog (renedering) performace? Currently 1M log requests is taking around 10 seconds.

We are already using AsyncTargets, but we were hoping we could get the actual rendering to be performed on another thread. The following code takes about 12 seconds with logging, but about 2 seconds without.

Thanks in advance.

```
        LoggingConfiguration config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();

        MyFirstTarget asyncTarget = new MyFirstTarget();

        var asyncFileTarget = new NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper(asyncTarget)
        {
            Name = "asyncTarget",
            QueueLimit = 1000000,
            OverflowAction = NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Grow
        };

        config.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, asyncFileTarget);

        Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            var cls = new MyClass
            {
                One = "Good One" + i,
                Two = "Buckle Shoe" + i
            };

            var info = new LogEventInfo()
            {
                Level = LogLevel.Info,
                Message = "{@cls}",
                Parameters = new[] { cls }
            };

            logger.Log(info);
        }

        sw.Stop(); //2 seconds without logging; 12 with.

        Console.WriteLine($"Time - {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
```

Comment: Yes NLog will perform rendering upfront when meeting a volatile object. To avoid deferring the rendering until after the object was disposed/closed/aborted. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/performance#defer-message-formatting (You are ofcourse wellcome to create pull-request to optimize NLog even further. Maybe adding support for value-tuples that can guarantee that all properties will not change until being logged, thus allow rendering to be deferred).

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thanks for the reply. Since we're trying to defer writing of a (semi)mutable object, it's being performed on the executing thread.

Comment: Maybe you should compare it with writing 1 million lines to a file. It's really dependent of your disk performance.